# PIP very slow when using it in a conda environment

Tags: python, pip, conda

It has been some months since the problem appeared from nowhere, every time I install something using `pip` from a `conda` environment (fresh or old) it takes ages to start the process, i have been using `-vvv` for debugging the issue.

When i'm using the main `conda` environment the output look like the following:

```bash
Using pip 21.1.3 from /localdisk/<username>/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
Non-user install because site-packages writeable
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-79hpacew
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-2x18ocvp
...
```

while if I am in an environment the output looks like this:

```bash
Using pip 23.0.1 from /localdisk/lpuglia/anaconda3/envs/vpunn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
Non-user install because site-packages writeable
[*** HERE PIP HANGS FOR ABOUT 2 MINUTES ***]
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-build-tracker-xb9h_yb9
Initialized build tracking at /tmp/pip-build-tracker-xb9h_yb9
...
```

besides the obvious difference in version between the two `pip`s, I really can't say what is the problem. Using `-vvv` doesn't shed any light on the source of the problem. I was expecting some hanging due to network problems but from the output it looks like that the hang happens before creating a folder.

Interestingly enough, if I call `pip` again just after it finishes (few seconds) it doesn't hang for 2 minutes. This time window is very small, waiting for 10 seconds will force another hang on the next `pip` installation.

I'm out of ideas on how to debug this issue, if anyone could suggest a way to understand better the problem or a solution it would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: it looks like that synchronizing pip version across base environment and the working environment solves the problem. Not sure why this happens, but any other answer with a better explanation will be accepted as the correct one.

EDIT:

We finally figured an explanation, it looks like that `pip` checks the content of `/etc/` before doing anything. For some reason, our machine had broken link to unavailable nfs partition in the `/etc/` folder. We just had to remove the broken link and now `pip` is not hanging anymore. To check if this is your scenario try to `ls /etc`, if it hangs, so `pip` will.